# Google Query - Generic column references for labeling

Tags: google-query-language

I'm building a quality assurance sheet which automatically pulls values from one tab, to a separate one, for each agent.

I'll need to write one per agent. To simply the process, would it be possible to reference the first column selected without specfiyng it by letter?

So GROUP BY and LABEL could be X where X so I only need to edit the select row.

Below is the current query I am using.

`=QUERY('Bimonthly Report 2017'!A:AN,
"SELECT D, sum(F)/count(F), sum(L)/count(L)
 WHERE F >0
 GROUP BY D
 LABEL D 'Category'"
 , 2)`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Just input the data as a array literal.

```
   =QUERY({'Bimonthly Report 2017'!A:AN}, "SELECT Col4, sum(Col6)/count(Col6), sum(Col12)/count(Col12) WHERE Col6 >0 GROUP BY Col4 LABEL Col4 'Category'" , 2)
```